# Why does my DataGridView DataSource not drawing rows?

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview, ienumerable, datasource

I have a problem with my DataGridView.DataSource and it has consumed me a lot of time solving this problem. Below is the code:

```
string[] queryWords = singleQuery.Split(' ');           // Split the query words according the "space" character

// Compose the SQL select query
string selectClause = @"SELECT ID, CategoryID, Name, UnitID, Price, QuantityAgen, QuantityBanjer, QuantityMalalayang, QuantitySorong FROM Product WHERE ";

// Add the where clauses inside the SQL select query
for (int i = 0; i < queryWords.Length; i++)
{
    selectClause += "(Name LIKE '%" + queryWords[i] + "%')";
    if (i < queryWords.Length - 1)
        selectClause += " AND ";
}

// Initiate the query and get the appropriate results
IEnumerable<SumberRejekiProgram.Code.Product> resultQuery = dbProduct.ExecuteQuery<SumberRejekiProgram.Code.Product>(selectClause);
var finalResult = from p in resultQuery
                  select new { Name = p.Name, Price = p.Price, Unit = p.Unit.Name };

// Bind the DataGridView according to the final query result in resultQuery variable
dgvSearch.DataSource = resultQuery;
```

When I debug the code, both "resultQuery" and "finalResult" contain the results that I want. However, when I set the "dgvSearch.DataSource", the results do not appear in the row even if I tried both `dgvSearch.DataSource = resultQuery` and `dgvSearch.DataSource = finalResult`. The DataGridView is just empty (except the column).

I debug "dgvSearch" after the code execution to make sure DataSource works properly and it does. All the results are inside DataSource, but somehow the DataGridView won't display it although I have called `dgvSearch.show()`.

Can anyone help me on this? I feel like I want to kill myself T_T.
Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: WHY do you think somebody should help you if you will not thank him??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you calling `dgvSearch.DataBind()` after you set its `DataSource` property?

Also, using string concatenation directly in your SQL is very, very bad (do a quick search for "SQL Injection"). Either make your query parameterized or roll that into your Linq query. Depending on the specific provider you're using, this may or may not work:

```
// Initiate the query and get the appropriate results
var resultQuery = from p in dbProduct.Product
                  select new { Name = p.Name, Price = p.Price, Unit = p.Unit.Name };

// Add the where clauses
for (int i = 0; i < queryWords.Length; i++)
{
    resultQuery = resultQuery.Where(p => p.Name.Contains(queryWords[i]));
}

// Bind the DataGridView according to the final query result in resultQuery variable
dgvSearch.DataSource = resultQuery;
dgvSearch.DataBind();
```

Comment: there is no dgvSearch.DataBind(); in vs 2013

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that you've set your LINQ query up to run but you haven't actually executed it yet, even when you attempt to bind its results to your DataGridView.  To execute your LINQ query you need to 'touch' the query results, such as in a `for` loop or by calling `ToList()`.  This is called 'deferred execution.'

So change the line where you bind to this and it should work (assuming your code is otherwise correct):

```
dgvSearch.DataSource = resultQuery.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try calling the Page.DataBind method after you set the datasource.

You might also try using a bindingsource as documented here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z.aspx#Y210